# Exponential MGF

Tags: probability, self-study, moment-generating-function

Let $T$ be a random variable with the probability density function (PDF) $f(t) = \lambda e^{−λ(t−a)}$, $\lambda > 0$, $t > a$. Find the moment generating function (MGF) of $T$.

This appears to be an exponential PDF with rate $(t-a)$, but I am having trouble with the integration to derive the MGF.

Answer (score 1):

That is actually a shifted exponential distribution with rate $\lambda$.  Here's a hint for you.  The MGF of $T$ is given by:

\begin{eqnarray*}
M_{T}(s) & = & E[e^{sT}]\\
 & = & \int_{a}^{\infty}e^{st}e^{-\lambda(t-a)}dt\\
 & = & \lambda\int_{a}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda t+\lambda a+st}dt\\
 & = & \lambda e^{\lambda a}\int_{a}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda t+st}dt\\
 &  & \lambda e^{\lambda a}\int_{a}^{\infty}e^{-t\left(\lambda-s\right)}dt
\end{eqnarray*}

Let $\lambda-s=k$, then

\begin{eqnarray*}
\lambda e^{\lambda a}\int_{a}^{\infty}e^{-t\left(\lambda-s\right)}dt & = & \lambda e^{\lambda a}\int_{a}^{\infty}e^{-tk}dt\\
\end{eqnarray*}

So this should now just be a simple matter of finding $\int_{a}^{\infty}e^{-tk}dt$.  Are you having trouble finding this integral?  This last integral can be found in any introductory calculus textbook.